# Codeigniter + MySQL - Search containing string

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search

I have column in table of database with value: PL TOFLEX NEGRO/PRETO

I search in my website: TOFLEX PRETO

I need output: PL TOFLEX NEGRO/PRETO

Can someone give me correct query to do this?
I try:

```
public function searchMaterial($nome)
{
    $json = [];

    $this->load->database();

    if(!empty($this->input->get("q"))){
        $this->db->like('nomeMaterial', $nome, 'both');
        $query = $this->db->select('idMaterial as id,nomeMaterial as text')
                    ->limit(50)
                    ->get("material");
        $json = $query->result();

    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: When you search like `TOFLEX PRETO`, It will be considered as a whole search word. So sql query will not show you `TOFLEX NEGRO/PRETO` in output. Try search using `TOFLEX` or `NEGRO` or `PRETO`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your terms before querying your database.
I assume `nomeMaterial` is the name of your column.

Try this if you want your column contains BOTH terms :

```
$search = 'TOFLEX PRETO';
$terms = explode(' ',$search); //will return an array with two strings
foreach($terms as $term){
    $this->db->like('nomeMaterial', $term);
}
```

Or try this if you want your columns contains at least one of the terms :

```
$search = 'TOFLEX PRETO';
$terms = explode(' ',$search); //will return an array with two strings
foreach($terms as $term){
    $this->db->or_like('nomeMaterial', $term);
}
```